# How to set up grid on remote machien and run webdriver test cases?

Tags: jenkins, webdriver, maven-3, selenium-grid

What I have; I have putty.exe to access a remote ubuntu machine xxx.xx.xxx.xx. 
What I want; I want that when I run my test cases on this remote machine using jenkins it would launch a browser that I can see popping up on my windows machine.
What I have tried; I have tried to use firefox with Xvfb(both located on remote machine) but that is headless and I cant see errors, I cant get much help from reports. I want to see whats happening on UI
So I wanted to use remote webdriver. I tried to register on remote machine as;used putty.exe

```
sudo java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar -role node  -hub http://localhost/xxx.xx.xxx.xx:4444/grid/register
```

but that gave error :

```
Sep 27, 2013 9:24:24 AM org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher main
INFO: Launching a selenium grid node
Sep 27, 2013 9:24:24 AM org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.SelfRegisteringRemote startRemoteServer
WARNING: error getting the parameters from the hub. The node may end up with wrong timeouts.The target server failed to respond
09:24:24.961 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 23.7-b01
09:24:24.962 INFO - OS: Linux 3.5.0-21-generic amd64
09:24:24.971 INFO - v2.35.0, with Core v2.35.0. Built from revision c916b9d
09:24:25.111 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:5555/wd/hub
09:24:25.113 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
09:24:25.114 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
09:24:25.115 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
09:24:25.116 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
09:24:36.415 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@49af0a45
09:24:36.416 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
09:24:36.423 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:5555
09:24:36.426 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@1f4a8824
09:24:36.428 INFO - using the json request : {"class":"org.openqa.grid.common.RegistrationRequest","capabilities":[{"platform":"LINUX","seleniumProtocol":"Selenium","browserName":"*firefox","maxInstances":5},{"platform":"LINUX","seleniumProtocol":"Selenium","browserName":"*googlechrome","maxInstances":5},{"platform":"LINUX","seleniumProtocol":"Selenium","browserName":"*iexplore","maxInstances":1},{"platform":"LINUX","seleniumProtocol":"WebDriver","browserName":"firefox","maxInstances":5},{"platform":"LINUX","seleniumProtocol":"WebDriver","browserName":"chrome","maxInstances":5},{"platform":"LINUX","seleniumProtocol":"WebDriver","browserName":"internet explorer","maxInstances":1}],"configuration":{"port":5555,"register":true,"host":"10.158.96.150","proxy":"org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy","maxSession":5,"role":"node","hubHost":"localhost","registerCycle":5000,"hub":"http://localhost/184.73.224.98:4444/grid/register","hubPort":-1,"url":"http://10.158.96.150:5555","remoteHost":"http://10.158.96.150:5555"}}
09:24:36.430 INFO - Starting auto register thread. Will try to register every 5000 ms.
09:24:36.430 INFO - Registering the node to hub :http://localhost:-1/grid/register
09:24:36.446 INFO - couldn't register this node : Error sending the registration request.
09:24:41.479 INFO - couldn't register this node : Hub is down or not responding: Hub is down or not responding.
```

I have already tried :
http://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2012/01/23/setting-up-grid2-and-working-with-it/
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2 
[Understanding Selenium Grid2 implementation running on EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148198/understanding-selenium-grid2-implementation-running-on-ec2)

but these failed on initial step when I have to register a node on remote ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 0):

Its not entirely clear what your error is. This might help where you can vnc onto a headless Xvfb box using ssh tunnels

after installing any missing packages on your remote server

```
Xvfb -screen 0 800x600x16 -ac &
export DISPLAY=:0
xterm &
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar -role node  -hub http://mywebsiteip:4444/grid/register
```

then tunnel to your server from your own machine

```
ssh -l kaltpost -L 5900:localhost:5900 mywebsiteip 'x11vnc -localhost -display :0'
```

which will wait, so in another terminal

```
vncviewer localhost&
```

Which is all taken from here http://gpio.kaltpost.de/?page_id=84

++edit 
I just saw you started your selenium server with the ip of the host, this needs to be localhost and then mywebsite id when you connect your tests to it

Comment: Do you mean that I should try : sudo java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar -role node  -hub http://localhost/xxx.xx.xxx.xx:4444/grid/register. If yes I have edited the post with the error and if no then it means I couldnt understand it correctly, please let me know how to achieve. One more thing Xvfb is not an issue I am able to run test cases using it but issue is I want see node (browser) popping up and visible on my machine like remote driver.